# NLB Accessed Denied from second server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, cluster, nlb, mirroring

Have NLB set up and working. Just two servers, web1 and web2. I set up NLB on web1 and can view both machines as Converged. (I had to specify a login/pass to connect to web2). On web2, looking at the NLB Manager, it only shows web2 and says in the log "Accessed Denied. Error connecting to web1".

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Often the NLB manager doesn't refresh it's view so the access denied error message may be stale. Try restarting it.

Another thing to check is the cluster type (unicast or multicast) and which adaptor you are connecting to as part of the cluster. If you have picked the cluster address on one side and not the other it may appear to be working, it just depends on whether the request was redirected to the correct machine at the time the request was made.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue multiple times and what i have seen as a simple solution is -
the DNS resolution fails in most cases and thus the error.
a work around can be - include the IP address, alias and the hostname of the machine you are adding in your cluster.

HOST file is ideally in the following location of your windows 2008 server - C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\"

-Djay.

Answer (score -1):

MAke sure you use the same password on both for setting up NLB.

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to have the same password for two administrator accounts on different machines?

Comment: No when settiung up NLB you pick a password. I have not done it for a while so....